# How might I download the binaries if both getmonero.org and github.com/monero-project are blocked?

Tags: github, getmonero-website, installation, download

How might I download the binaries if both **getmonero.org** and **github.com/monero-project** are blocked?

Let us assume the following initial conditions:

- I have Tor installed on my Linux-based OS.
- I already have [I2P](https://geti2p.net/) (but not I2P-zero) installed on my OS.
- **github.com/i2p-zero** is also blocked.
- I am in a country where they just blocked both
  **getmonero.org** and **github.com/monero-project**
- The bandwidth available via Tor seems to be the bottleneck
  that precludes downloading the binaries via both `torsocks wget https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/download/v0.17.2.0/monero-linux-x64-v0.17.2.0.tar.bz2` and `torsocks wget https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/linux64`.
  The same bottleneck makes it impossible for me to clone the repo
  from Github by executing: `torsocks git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero.git`. That even precludes compiling from source.

Are there any [IPFS](https://ipfs.io)-based mirrors of whom I am not yet aware of?
Does anyone on the Web offer alternative downloads via Bittorrent? Is there a rescue-type service like [gettor](https://gettor.torproject.org/)?
Where can I get the signing keys from in the situation that I described? Are any [eepsites](https://geti2p.net/) that are helpful in overcoming such censorship?

Comment: So it works through Tor? Have you tried doing it through Tor, and waiting a long time?

Comment: @user253751 I did and failed, after 20-30min, to clone the repo. But even if I succeded let us not consider cloning the repo via Tor as a means of solving the problem. The scenario is for the sake of education.

Comment: Tor and i2p should both be fine for accessing the GitHub repository.

Comment: @jtgrassie How do I use i2p to clone the repo? Is there in i2p a command that would do the job (like `torsocks` does it in Tor)?

Comment: http://geti2p.net/en/about/browser-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading source and release binaries works fine over Tor and I2P.

Answer (score 0):

Try it over my bridge, obfs4 or natively:

```
obfs4 [2a01:4f8:bc:a09::3]:4443 C613C124590D64AEA98BC675B2CC34F4A47BDAA7 cert=QDkFcq56pfY58CXLbLAL4pcDPSDkv8JIQXOMsZxpeQgpOBcJaR/QUF3FokFt27BMB0VXEw iat-mode=0
obfs4 185.185.24.52:4443 C613C124590D64AEA98BC675B2CC34F4A47BDAA7 cert=QDkFcq56pfY58CXLbLAL4pcDPSDkv8JIQXOMsZxpeQgpOBcJaR/QUF3FokFt27BMB0VXEw iat-mode=0
```

Download `monero-linux-x64-v0.17.2.0.tar.bz2` from github took just 3 mins.